# unicorn master failed to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

i try to start a app via nginx & unicorn .
i start server successfully for 3 time bye similar codes.
but i usually see this :

```
[root@server yaqoot]# unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:88:in `block in reload': directory for stderr_path=/var/www/yaqoot/log/unicorn/log not writable (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:84:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:84:in `reload'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:65:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:76:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:76:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
master failed to start, check stderr log for details
```

how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's stated in the error message:

```
/var/www/yaqoot/log/unicorn/log not writable
```

So,

- you need to set different path for err logging

or

- you need to run unicorn as a proper user

or

- you need to chown/change permissions for this folder